# Error al Enviar formulario, Me da error en validator laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

Tengo el siguiente error, estoy intentando enviar un formulario que también contiene una imagen con ajax, lo envío normalmente pero me da un error 500 al enviar el formulario y validarlo aun no [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]se porque.
Este es mi Ajax.

```
 $('#btn_enviar').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).html('Sending..');
        var url = $(this).data('uri');

        $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          }
        });

        $.ajax({
          data: $('#profesor').serialize(),
          url: url,
          type: "POST",
          success: function (data) {
            alert("recibido");

          },
          error: function (data) {
              //console.log('Error:', data);
              alert("error");
              $('#btn_enviar').html('Save Changes');
          }
      });
    });
```

Esta es mi ruta
Route::POST('/SuperAdmin/StoreProfesor', 'ProfesorController@store')->name('SuperAdmin.StoreProfesor');

Y mi controlador con su validación

```
$json = $request->input('profesor',null);
        $params_array = json_decode($json,true);
        $params = json_decode($json);


       if (!empty($params_array)) {
            $validator = Validator::make($request, [
                'nombre'          =>      'required|alpha',
                'ap_p'            =>      'required|alpha',
                'ap_m'            =>      'required|alpha',
                'direccion'       =>      'required|alpha',
                'image'           =>      'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png'
            ]);


            if ($validacion->fails()) {

                $data = array(
                    'status'    => 'error',
                    'code'      =>  404,
                    'mensaje'   =>  'El profesor no se a registrado correctamente',
                    'errors'    =>  $validacion->errors()

                );

            }else {


               $file = $request->file();

                $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();

                Storage::disk('public')->put($name,\File::get($file));

                $profesor = new profesor();
                $profesor->nombre = $params_array['nombre'];
                $profesor->apellido_p = $params_array['ap_p'];
                $profesor->apellido_m = $params_array['ap_m'];
                $profesor->direccion = $params_array['direccion'];
                $profesor->url_foto = $name;
                $profesor->save();
```

Si entro a mi controlador pero me da un erro que no se como resolverlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Validator::make` espera como primer argumento un array, pero le estas pasando todo el objeto Request cuando haces:

```
Validator::make($request, [ //...
```

Puedes obtener todos los datos de entrada que están en el Request como un array utilizando el método `all()`, entonces en tu código puedes escribirlo así:

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [ //...
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: antes utilizaba lo siguiente:
Validator::make($params_array, [...
pero me arrojaba el mismo error

Comment: Que valor tiene $params_array? Veo que haces un json_decode,del input profesor. Es un json lo que llega en ese input?  Podrías hacer un dd($request->all()); y mostrar el resultado?

Comment: Antes que nada muchas gracias por contestarme, mira segun mi logica tal vez me equivoco jeje, yo recibo mi formulario con id profesor, tal vez tengo el error ahí

Comment: Bueno, eso no lo puedo saber con el código que publicaste, por eso te digo lo del dd($request->all()); , que te va a mostrar que es lo que está llegando al controlador. Otra forma de verlo sería que en la primer linea del método del controlador pongas return $request->all();  y en la función success de ajax pongas un consolé.log(data.data)

Comment: @Edgar lo resolviste asi entonces? Veo que aceptaste la respuesta

Comment: Si, muchas gracias, lo que pasa es que yo trataba de recibir en la siguiente linea 
$json = $request->input('profesor',null); lo el formulario y quería manjerlo de esa manera pero  me daba null, y pues lo maneje de la manera en que me comentaste y me envió perfectamente